# How to use an image as background with [ngStyle] Angular 5

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a `Div` have a background that have been saved in the Data Base 
so I tried using [ngStyle] in Angular but it didn't worked

```
<div class="image" [ngStyle]="{'background': ' url(' + imageUrl  + ') no-repeat 0 0'}"></div>
```

but when i use it as

```
<img [src]="imageUrl || img.src" alt="" class="img">
```

it worked

Answer (score 2):

You can use `height` and `width` of `div`.

```
<div class="image" style="height: 300px;width:300px;" [ngStyle]="{'background': ' url(' + imageUrl  + ') no-repeat 0 0'}"></div>
```

Comment: the problem is that the image is not defined

Comment: with the Devtool this is what i got `<div _ngcontent-c4="" class="image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background: url(&quot;undefined&quot;) 0px 0px no-repeat;"></div>`

Comment: I have create a demo on Stackblitz- https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-use-an-image-as-background-with-ngstyle-angular-5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: my problem is that the image i want to use is storage in the Data Base

Comment: that would've worked if the `imageUrl` was a `string` that have the source but in my app `imageUrl` is the image itself

Answer (score 2):

Does this work .?

```
[style.background-image]="'url('+imageUrl+')'"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `height` and `width` of div tag. Beacuse **div** tag height and width by default is 0px:

```
<div class="image" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + (imageUrl)? imageUrl : none  + ')  no-repeat 0 0', 'height': '200px', 'width': '200px'}"></div>
```

You need to check condition for `imageUrl` like this:

```
(imageUrl)? imageUrl : none
```

Comment: i set both `height` and `with` for it in the css file

Comment: I tried your method but this is what i got `<div _ngcontent-c3="" class="image" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;"></div>`

Comment: @حذيفهالشرامي Yes. So here When your `imageUrl` is undefined then it set background to none. Which will be not shown in your `Devtool`

Comment: Yes this the problem but when i use an `img` inested of `Div` and use the `[src]` it worked great